# Add values from one IEnumerable<Type1> to other IEnumerable<Type2>

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say that we have two object types:

```
class Type1
{
    public int Value {get;set;}
}

class Type2
{
    public int Val {get; set;}
}
```

And we have two IEnumerable's for them:

```
IEnumerable<Type1> type1col;
IEnumerable<Type2> type2col;
```

What I want to have: each of `type1col` elements `Value` property value would have adequate `type2col` `Val` property value added.

We can say that both IEnumerables will have the same length always.

For now I am using this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < type1col.Count(); i++)
{
    type1col.ElementAt(i).Value += type2col.ElementAt(i).Val;
}
```

but is there any better (faster & shorter) approach to do the same?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with this approach. You may want to check for length equality but otherwise this is fine.

Comment: It is working fine, both IEnumerables are always of same length, but I just wondered if there is any other approach without using `for` loop and index.

Comment: If the types implement `IList<T>` this will be an O(N) operation, but if they do not it will be an O(N^2) operation, which could be a problem for you if the lists are long.

Comment: Actually both Ienumerables are `List<>`

Comment: @MatthewWatson: This could be worked around by using both enumerators directly (still assuming equal length, of course).

Comment: Then use the indexed approach instead of using `IEnumerable.ElementAt()`.

Comment: I think Matthew has highlighted the only potential problem and if this is the case declare two variables and call .ToList on each enum. then iterate over the lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`IEnumerable.Zip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd267698(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var type1Col = type1Col.Select(x => x.Value)
    .Zip(type2Col.Select(x => x.Value), (x, y) => x + y)
    .Select(x => new Type1 { Value = x });
```

But as you allready have simple lists you can also use a classic loop and use indexers instead of `IEnumerable.ElementAt`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < type1Col.Count; i++)
{
    type1Col[i].Value += typeo2Col[i];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Enumerating both together would be faster

```
[Benchmark]
public static void Enumerator()
{
    using (var enumerator1 = Type1S.GetEnumerator())
    {
        using (var enumerator2 = Type2S.GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (enumerator1.MoveNext() && enumerator2.MoveNext())
            {
                enumerator1.Current.Value += enumerator2.Current.Val;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do an in-place modification of the elements of a sequence rather than having the overhead of creating a new sequence using `Zip()` you could do something like this:

```
public static void Combine<T1, T2>(IEnumerable<T1> target, IEnumerable<T2> modifyier, Action<T1, T2> modify)
{
    using (var seq1 = target.GetEnumerator())
    using (var seq2 = modifyier.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (seq1.MoveNext() && seq2.MoveNext())
        {
            modify(seq1.Current, seq2.Current);
        }
    }
}
```

Which you would use like this:

```
IEnumerable<Type1> typecol1 = new List<Type1>{new Type1{Value = 1 }, new Type1 { Value = 2 } };
IEnumerable<Type2> typecol2 = new List<Type2>{new Type2{Val = 3}, new Type2{ Val = 4 } };

Combine(typecol1, typecol2, (type1, type2) => type1.Value += type2.Val);

foreach (var item in typecol1)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
}
```